# SQL Server DateTime with timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to show datetime in following format with TimeZone associated:

```
7/19/2017 10:15:55 AM CST
```

Is it possible to show this in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: Store the Time Zone in separate column - which will be generally Time Zone set on the database server during time of record creation or update. By this way you can either show time in CST or can convert to any time zone at the time of display to end user

Comment: For future readers, I use `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 120) --YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ± NN:NN`. The timezone is the server timezone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this query ;

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),1) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),9), 14)
```

if you wanted to add timezone try this :

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT


select CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),1) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),9), 14) + ' ' + @TimeZone
```

Comment: Word of warning: this will show timezone of the server, while with this example this is fine - you show current datetime on the server. However is you would show datetime from data, you have to have this information stored along with datetime column.

Comment: @GustiArya Awesome dude. Just one quick question - I did not understand your word of warning. How would I store this information with my datetime column?

Comment: @RameshwarPawale that is Rafal Ziolwski comment, I dont know how to do it either

Comment: Oops sorry. I didn't see it. Marking your answer :)

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski Can you elaborate your word of warning?

Comment: @RameshwarPawale "this will show timezone of the server, while with this example this is fine - you show current datetime on the server. However is you would show datetime from data, you have to have this information stored along with datetime column"

Comment: @RameshwarPawale You must store the time zone in another column. None of the date-time datatypes in SQL Server include the time zone. DATETIMEOFFSET stores (internally) UTC plus the _time zone offset_ of the time zone from where the value came.

Answer (score 4):

Based on on your question please try `datetimeoffset`:

Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @datetimeoffset datetimeoffset(4) = getdate();  
SELECT @datetimeoffset AS 'CurrentTimeAndLocation'
```

Result example:

```
CurrentTimeAndLocation
2017-07-20 09:03:48.7270 +00:00
```

Also if you would like to play with dates and time data types and functions please take at look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: Offset is not the same as timezone. Offsets might change in some timezone due to DST. OP asks for timezone abbreviations.