# SQLite - TZ format to Date time only using SQL queries

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a SQLite database with a simple table in the format of:

```
ID,DateText,Name
1,2020-09-01T18:57:17Z,John
2,2022-12-01T04:00:09Z,Laurel
...
```

The `DateText` column is declared as `TEXT` on the "create table" statement. **Using only SQL**, I need to:

1. Create a new column with the `DateText` data.
2. Obtain the "oldest" date
3. Obtain the "newest" date

Note that **I need to resolve this with a SQL query**. I cannot read into a programming language, parse, and update table--I need to do everything on SQL. For example, [SQL Server DateTime with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205982/sql-server-datetime-with-timezone) is the opposite, but they are using node.js, something I cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the oldest and newest using `min()` and `max()`:

```
SELECT ID, min(DateTime), Name FROM YourTable; -- Oldest
SELECT ID, max(DateTime), Name FROM YourTable; -- Newest
```

The nice thing about ISO-8601 date and time format strings is that they sort lexicographically without having to do anything special with them.

---

These queries would give an error on most SQL database engines because of the mix of non-grouped columns with an aggregate function, but SQLite explicitly will return the row that goes with the minimum or maximum column value. And of course if you don't want the other columns, just leave them out of the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the earliest and latests, but not how to convert the date format.